# SQL to find emails that have custID 0 AND custID <> 0

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, having

I have an ecommerce database that contains an 'Order' table (tblOrders). In this table there are individual orders with OrderTotal, Name, Email, etc. If the user checks out as 'guest', a CustID of 0 will be added. If a user checks out and creates or logs in as a customer, then there will be a CustID value that is not 0 (int).

I'm trying to find customers (distinct email) that have order as a logged in user (not 0) but also checked out as a guest (0). I want to find these records to assign their guest checkouts to their customer ID.

I keep trying a combination of INNER JOINs and HAVING, but I keep banging my head. Hoping for a fresh perspective.

For the sake of simplicity, here is a very stripped down schema of that table.

```
CREATE TABLE `tblOrders` (
    `OrderID` int NOT NULL,
    `CustID` int NOT NULL,
    `Email` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `tblOrders`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`),
    ADD KEY `CustID` (`CustID`),
    ADD KEY `Email` (`Email`);
ALTER TABLE `tblOrders`
  MODIFY `OrderID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO tblOrders(OrderID, CustID, Email)
VALUES(1,0,'test@test.com');
INSERT INTO tblOrders(OrderID, CustID, Email)
VALUES(2,1,'test@test.com');
INSERT INTO tblOrders(OrderID, CustID, Email)
VALUES(3,0,'blah@blah.com');
INSERT INTO tblOrders(OrderID, CustID, Email)
VALUES(4,0,'joe@blah.com');
INSERT INTO tblOrders(OrderID, CustID, Email)
VALUES(5,2,'joe@blah.com');
INSERT INTO tblOrders(OrderID, CustID, Email)
VALUES(6,3,'mary@blah.com');
```

In this example, I would look to get a record set that shows test@test.com and joe@blah.com as having both customer record and a guest record. This result set would not include blah@blah.com since that email only has a guest record and it would not show mary@blah.com because she only has a customer record (no guest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having` for filtering:

```
select email
from tblOrders
group by email
having min(custID) = 0   -- ordered at least once as guest
   and max(custID) > 0   -- and at least once as non-guest
```

This assumes that there are no negative `custID`s, which seems relevant for your use case.

There are various ways to phrase the `having` clause to match the requirement, here are a few alternatives:

```
having max(custID = 0) = 1 and max(custID > 0) = 1
having min(custID) = 0 and max(custID) <> min(custID)
```